# isEqualToNumber give error message invalid receiver type NSUinteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I'm struggling with a simple condition because I am new to iphone development. My question is I want to compare two integer values

I define one integer like `NSInteger i= indexPath.row;`

And I check it in condition for `indexpath.row` is same or not :
like this

```
if ([indexPath.row isEqualToNumber:i])
    {
        if([appDelegate.flag isEqualToString:@"flag"])
        {   CardName.text=appDelegate.fieldVal;
            appDelegate.flag=@" ";
        }
    }

    else {

        CardName.text=cellValue;  

    }
```

Please tell me if this is the correct way to go. If so, why do I get a a warning like:

> invalid receiver type NSUinteger (and then my simulator terminates)

Answer (score 4):

`row` property in NSIndexPath is a plain integer, not a NSNumber object, so your comparison should be just

```
if (indexPath.row == i)
   ...
```

Comment: Nope, it should be `if (indexPath.row == i)
   …`, without the `]` :)